# Check if character varying is between range of numbers

Tags: postgresql, groovy

I hava data in my database and i need to select all data where 1 column number is between 1-100.
Im having problems, because i cant use - `between 1 and 100;` Because that column is character varying, not integer. But all data are numbers (i cant change it to integer).

Code;

```
dst_db1.eachRow("Select length_to_fault from diags where length_to_fault between 1 AND 100")
```

Error - operator does not exist: character varying >= integer

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS, you should be able to cast the value to integer and then do the comparison.

Comment: i need to write only groovy script. I cant change anything in database

Comment: Look up casting in SQL. It is a more complex select statement than you have now, that will be in your Groovy code.

Comment: I changed Select part to - ```select length_to_fault from diags where cast(length_to_fault as integer) between 1 and 100```. And now error says - invalid input syntax for type integer: "32.12". Any suggestions here?

Comment: With respect, go and read up on the SQL syntax for your DB. SQL is very powerful, but you need to learn the basics.

Comment: Here's a hint. Where your-cast-expreeion > 1 and your-cast-expression < 100

Comment: Yes, but then i have a new error - sql invalid input syntax for type double precision n/a. There is also n/a values in database, but i dont know what to do in this case... I also changed int to float.

Comment: Am I the only one missing the so called "groovy" in this question?

Comment: Im writing this in groovy, but i publiced only select part...

Answer (score 0):

The below PostgreSQL query will work

```
SELECT length_to_fault FROM diags WHERE regexp_replace(length_to_fault, '[\s+]', '', 'g')::numeric BETWEEN 1 AND 100;
```

Comment: It could work if i had full numbers, but since i have something like 32.12, integer cant be used... And if i change data type to float, it shows error about double precision: "N/A". In data base some inserts is n/a, maybe thats why it shows it? Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I fixed everything. Thanks, your select works aswell. I just added - ```length_to_fault != 'N/A' . ``` so it ignores N/A and my float can work on numbers

Comment: Replace 'N/A' with the desired output using 'regexp_replace'

Answer (score 0):

Since your column supposed to contain numeric values but is defined as text (or version of text) there will be times when it does not i.e. You need 2 validations: that the column actually contains numeric data and that it falls into your value restriction. So add the following predicates to your query.

```
and length_to_fault ~ '^\+?\d+(\.\d*)?$' 
and length_to_fault::numeric <@ ('[1.0,100.0]')::numrange;
```

The first builds a [regexp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) that insures the column is a valid floating point value. The second insures the numeric value fall within the specified [numeric range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY). See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cab71a75fe0e57175bee6d38f486866).  

I understand you cannot change the database, but this looks like a good place for a check constraint esp. if n/a is the only non-numeric are allowed. You may want to talk with your DBA ans see about the following constraint.

```
alter table diags 
      add constraint length_to_fault_check
          check (   lower(length_to_fault) = 'n/a' 
                 or (    length_to_fault ~ '^\+?\d+(\.\d*)?$' 
                     and length_to_fault::numeric <@ ('[1.0,100.0]')::numrange
                    )
                 );
```

Then your query need only check that:

```
lower(lenth_to_fault) != 'n/a'
```